# How to import from CSV

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to parse data from several *.csv files and save them as list for later manipulation, but keep failing.

I have read numerous tutorials and related topics on SO and other sites, but couldn't find the solution for my problem. After several days of working on the code, I am stuck and don't know how to proceed.

```
# saves filepaths of *.csv files in lists (constant)
CSV_OLDFILE = glob.glob("./oldcsv/*.csv")
assert isinstance(CSV_OLDFILE, list)
CSV_NEWFILE = glob.glob("./newcsv/*.csv")
assert isinstance(CSV_NEWFILE, list)

def get_data(input):
    """copies numbers from *.csv files, saves them in list RAW_NUMBERS"""
    for i in range(0, 5): # for each of the six files
        with open(input[i], 'r') as input[i]: # open as "read"
            for line in input[i]: # parse lines for data
                input.append(int(line)) # add to list
                return input

def write_data(input):
    """writes list PROCESSED_NUMBERS_FINAL into new *.csv files"""
    for i in range(0, 5): # for each of the six files
        with open(input[i], 'w') as data: # open as "write"
            data = csv.writer(input[i])
            return data

RAW_NUMBERS = get_data(CSV_OLDFILE)
# other steps for processing data
write_data(PROCESSED_NUMBERS_FINAL)
```

Actual result:

```
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
```

Expected result: save data from *.csv files, manipulate and write them to new *.csv files.

I think the problem is probably located in my trying to call `len` of a `file` object, but I don't know what the correct implementation should look like.

Complete backtrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./solution.py", line 100, in <module>
    PROCESSED_NUMBERS = slowsort_start(RAW_NUMBERS)
  File "./solution.py", line 73, in slowsort_start
    (input[i], 0, len(input[i])-1))
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
```

Comment: Please include the complete backtrace in your question because it's difficult to tell what line is causing `len()` to be called.

Comment: I have added the complete backtrace. The function "slowsort_start" is used to start the sorting algorithm for sorting random numbers, which are parsed from *.csv files column A. Just to be sure: I did not include code with slowsort, as I didn't want to obscure my problem. It seems that I am using the wrong tool here to manipulate data, and I don't know the right answer.

Comment: Generally you need to include the source that is causing the error when posting questions here. That said I think the root cause might be the `with open(input[i], 'r') as input[i]:` which should be changed to something like `with open(input[i], 'r') as file:` and then `file` substituted for `input[i]` in the lines below it. You also shouldn't be using `input` as a variable name because it's the name of a built-in function. Doing that isn't causing the problem, but it's a poor Python programming practice.

Comment: Thank you, that explains why pylint was warning me of `Redefining built-in 'input' (redefined-builtin)` all the time. Good to know! And thank you too for your help with clarifying the problem. I will try it out as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: Expected result: read data from `*.csv`, manipulate numbers and write them to new `*.csv`.

`OOP` solution that holds the `numbers` in a `dict` of `dict:list`.

- Initialize the `class object` with the `in_path` and `out_path`

  ```
  import os, csv

  class ReadProcessWrite:
      def __init__(self, in_path, out_path):
          self.in_path = in_path
          self.out_path = out_path
          self.number = {}
  ```
- Read **all** files from `self.in_path`, filter `.csv` files.
  Create a `dict` with key `['raw']` and assign all `numbers` from this `*.csv` to a `list`.

  > **Note**: Assuming, **one** `number` per line!

  ```
      def read_numbers(self):
          for fname in os.listdir(self.in_path):
              if fname.endswith('.csv'):
                  self.number[fname] = {}
                  with open(os.path.join(self.in_path, fname)) as in_csv:
                      self.number[fname]['raw'] = [int(number[0]) for number in csv.reader(in_csv)]

                  print('read_numbers {} {}'.format(fname, self.number[fname]['raw']))
          return self
  ```
- Process the `['raw']` numbers and assigen the result to the key `['final']`.

  ```
      def process_numbers(self):
          def process(numbers):
              return [n*10 for n in numbers]

          for fname in self.number:
              print('process_numbers {} {}'.format(fname, self.number[fname]['raw']))
              # other steps for processing data
              self.number[fname]['final'] = process(self.number[fname]['raw'])
          return self
  ```
- Write the results from key `['final']` to `self.out_path`, using the same `.csv` filenames.

  ```
      def write_numbers(self):
          for fname in self.number:
              print('write_numbers {} {}'.format(fname, self.number[fname]['final']))
              with open(os.path.join(self.out_path, fname), 'w') as out_csv:
                  csv.writer(out_csv).writerows([[row] for row in self.number[fname]['final']])
  ```
- **Usage**:

  ```
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      ReadProcessWrite('oldcsv', 'newcsv').read_numbers().process_numbers().write_numbers()
  ```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> read_numbers 001.csv [1, 2, 3]
> read_numbers 003.csv [7, 8, 9]
> read_numbers 002.csv [4, 5, 6]
> process_numbers 003.csv [7, 8, 9]
> process_numbers 002.csv [4, 5, 6]
> process_numbers 001.csv [1, 2, 3]
> write_numbers 003.csv [70, 80, 90]
> write_numbers 002.csv [40, 50, 60]
> write_numbers 001.csv [10, 20, 30]
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. This looks really interesting and helpful. At the moment, though, I have found another solution which suits my needs as it is very easy to implement. But next time I need something like this again, I'll try your method.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution I found, after lots of trial-and-error and research:

```
# initializing lists for later use
RAW_DATA = [] # unsorted numbers
SORTED_DATA = [] # sorted numbers
PROCESSED_DATA = [] # sorted and multiplied numbers

def read_data(filepath): # from oldfiles
    """returns parsed unprocessed numbers from old *.csv files"""
    numbers = open(filepath, "r").read().splitlines() # reads, gets input from rows
    return numbers

def get_data(filepath): # from oldfiles
    """fills list raw_data with parsed input from old *.csv files"""
    for i in range(0, 6): # for each of the six files
        RAW_DATA.append(read_data(filepath[i])) # add their data to list

def write_data(filepath): # parameter: newfile
    """create new *.csv files with input from sorted_data and permission 600"""
    for i in range(0, 6): # for each of the six files
        with open(filepath[i], "w", newline="\n") as file: # open with "write"
            writer = csv.writer(file) # calls method for writing
            for item in SORTED_DATA[i]: # prevents data from being treated as one object
                writer.writerow([item]) # puts each entry in row
        os.chmod(filepath[i], 0o600) # sets permission to 600 (octal)
```

This lets me read from files, as well as create and write to files. Given that I need a specific setup, with data only ever being found in "column A", I chose this solution. But thanks again to everybody who answered and commented!